# Multiple column sorting in Angular material data table

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, angular-material-table

I want to sorting on multiple columns in a data table (Angular Material) where next sorting column will give me the result based on previous column sorting.

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(yourData);
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
    switch(property) {
        case 'project.isActive': return item.project.isActive;
        case 'project.start': return item.project.start;
        default: return item[property];
    }
};
this.dataSource.sort = sort;
```

Every time when I am sorting one column, it clears the previously sorted data.

Comment: As you stated, your code does not do what you want it to do. What have you tried so far? What is the exact issue you encountered?

Comment: I want to sort on multiple column at a time. E.x. if there are 2 columns like name, value then firstly I want to sort the data based on name column and then sort on value column